# 16.04 LTS Reboots after shutdown (Acer aspire E5-511)

Tags: shutdown, reboot

Upgraded to 16.04 as a way of fixing the networking bug introduced in recent 14.04LTS update. Now when I do a Shut down my laptop bursts back into life a few seconds after completely powering down. Have tried the grub update suggested in related threads and checked the Wake on LAN BIOS setting (disabled). Neither worked.
Go easy on me. I'm just a dumb user who would have gone nowhere near 16.04 yet if 14.04 hadn't broken my networking.

Comment: Do you have some more information on your hardware? For example, can you add the output of the command `lspci` (run in the terminal) to your question?